# Spingboot | Alternative to running with Intellij static and templates in resource folder

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

**Background:** We make Springboot web applications with Thymeleaf and React as the front end stack.

Our team's current process, is having two modules, 'client' and 'server' where on the gradle command "clean build" to have a custom task that will take the complied front end (index.html and the static js and css) and put it appropriately in the folders as you can see here:

[image]

When you run an application in Intellij, you can configure the project to either run with 'Gradle' or 'Intellij'. As shown below:

[image]

When you run with gradle, you do not actually need to copy the resources folder but instead just put them in the ${buildDir}. This is the default behavior and works great the majority of the time. If someone has 'run with Intellij' selected, then we need to add an additional copy task to have the compiled front end code into the active directory. (Not sure of the lingo there)

**Goal:** Find a way to run application where you do not need to have built recourses in static and templates folder no matter how you run application.

```
task copyClient(dependsOn: ":client:clientBuild") {
    doLast {
        //For Running with Gradle
        copy {
            from new File(project(":client").getProjectDir(), "build")
            into "${buildDir}/resources/main/static"
        }
        //For Running with Intellij
        copy {
            from new File(project(":client").getProjectDir(), "build/index.html")
            into "src/main/resources/static"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, not sure if you saw my comment on your now deleted question ... so: You are in the wrong place. We do not discuss the pros and cons of java language enhancements here. There is the JEP process, and there are zillions of related mailing lists. I suggest you start here mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo and pick an audience that better fits your idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any Gradle task as **Before**/**After** [trigger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html#config_triggers_gradle) to the IDE's own **Build** action:

[image]